# MongoClient dot vs standard key value access

Tags: node.js, mongodb, comparison

I ran into an interesting scenario today working on some code that I've been trying to research with no such luck as of yet.  Would like someone to shine some light on the situation if they can please.

Ingredients is a list of JSON objects that is stored in each recipe.  `dbIngredient` is a single ingredient I pull back using a `findOne` call with `MongoClient`.  The comparison is the `if` statement that is currently returning `false` if I have something like `tbsp` for both values.

```
recipe.ingredients.forEach(async (ingredient) => {
    // This will convert the ingredients as needed and form the grocery list.
    let dbIngredient = await db.collection('ingredients').findOne({ 'text_friendly_name': ingredient.text_friendly_name });
    if (dbIngredient.most_used_measurement != ingredient.measurement)
    {
        ingredient.quantity = unitConverter.convertMeasurement(ingredient.quantity, ingredient.measurement, dbIngredient.most_used_measurement);
    }
});
```

Using the `dot` notation doesn't appear to ever return a true, but if I use bracket notation like so `dbIngredient['most_used_measurement'] != ingredient['measurement']` the statement is evaluated as `true`.  Does anyone know why the `dot` notation fails but the `bracket` notation doesn't?

Comment: Can you post the code, please, where you're doing the actual comparison?

Comment: Ok.  Edited it to show the code snippet and ask a bit more clearly I hope.

Comment: Does `dbIngredient.most_used_measurement != ingredient['measurement']` work? Also, can you log one value of ingredient and dbIngredient?

Comment: The answer to first question is yes, it does work.  As for the second question, I previously logged the values and they looked the same the best I can tell.  So for instance in one test case, the value of `dbIngredient.most_used_measurement` was `tbsp` and the value of `ingredient.measurement` was also `tbsp`.

Comment: Hmm. I might be missing something very obvious here but it's getting late and I don't see anything that could be causing this strange behaviour. You could try to print out the values with some delimiter around them (as in `"tbsp"` and not just `tbsp`) and see what you get.